apt cache for live build
How can I cache all internet files when building with live-build? lb config --cache true --cache-packages true --cache-indices true does not work (see the last section of the build script and log).
After following tutorial 1 of the official live-build example:
# install latest live-build
git clone https://salsa.debian.org/live-team/live-build.git
cd live-build
git switch --detach 4f7f59f9e53bc29a4ec87130b90da3a04f118815
sudo make install

mkdir tutorial1
cd tutorial1

# set mirror for packages
sudo mkdir -p /etc/live
sudo tee '/etc/live/build.conf' << 'EOF' > /dev/null
LB_MIRROR_BOOTSTRAP="http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/"
LB_MIRROR_CHROOT_SECURITY="http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian-security/"
LB_MIRROR_CHROOT_BACKPORTS="http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian-backports/"
EOF

# explicitly enable package and package list caches
lb config --cache true --cache-packages true --cache-indices true

# download and build custom image
sudo lb build 2>&1 | tee build.log

# without clearing caches, rebuild
# through a network monitor, this downloads files again from the internet
sudo lb build 2>&1 | tee build.log

On the rebuild, this is what is redownloaded:
lb chroot_archives chroot remove
P: Deconfiguring file /etc/apt/sources.list
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable InRelease [151 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable-updates InRelease [55.4 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org stable-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main Sources [9489 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages [8786 kB]
...

Since they are http:// and not https://, I would expect these to be cached too.
